# Almacenar datos recibidos mediante Scanner

Tags: java, login, app

Buen día,

Estoy desarrollando una app de un cinema, y deseo que tenga una opción de logIn. Quiero que al solicitar datos mediante Scanner (registro), se queden guardados en algún archivo y así, luego al ingresar nuevamente al aplicativo, pueda usar los datos para Ingresar. He intentado usar FileWriter, pero no he entendido cómo funciona el comando. **Quiero saber si existe alguna forma más básica de generar ese metodo**, pues no soy muy hábil para Java aún. Quiero que el programa funcione en consola, o sea sin usar Jframes o algo así.

Edit: Lo que llevo es

```
public void menuLogeo() {
            String titulo="Sistema de Información"; 
            StringBuilder opciones=new StringBuilder(" B I E N V E N I D O \n ");
            opciones.append(" 1. LogIn\n");
            opciones.append(" 2. Registrarse\n");
            opciones.append(" 3. Salir del aplicativo\n");
            String mensaje=""; // Variable usada para distintos propósitos
            int opcion=0;
            System.out.println(opcion);
            while (opcion!=3) {
                opcion=Integer.parseInt((String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,opciones,titulo,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE));
                switch (opcion) {
                case 1: 
                    logIn();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    registro();
                    break;
                case 3:

                    break;

                }
            }
        }
    public void logIn() {
        System.out.println("Por favor indique su usuario:");
        entrada.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Por favor indique su contraseña:");
        entrada.nextLine();

    }
    public void registro() {
        System.out.println("Nombre de usuario deseado:");
        entrada.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Contraseña deseada:");
        entrada.nextLine();
    }
    }
```

Gracias por la atención prestada.

Comment: ¿Que has intentado hasta ahora? Agregalo en la pregunta!

Comment: ¿El archivo puede ser binario? O debe ser de texto?

Comment: Pues se me facilitaría uno de texto, para así tener la lista de los datos que se registran como una base de datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero vamos a especificar que tipo de formato tendrá el archivo donde guardaremos la cuenta de cada usuario.

En este ejemplo he usado este formato:

```java
archivo: users.txt
name,password
```

Esto quiere decir que si tengo 3 cuentas registradas en el archivo, se mirarán de esta forma:

```java
Jose,1234
David,dsr23
Pepe,23fs1
```

Así que el primer texto corresponde al nombre del usuario y el segundo a la contraseña.

> > Almacenar datos recibidos mediante Scanner

Para lograr guardar esos datos en un archivo, usaremos la clase [BufferedWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedWriter.html), donde esta clase me proporciona dos métodos:

- `void write(String)` para escribir datos de tipo `String` en el archivo.
- `void newLine()` para hacer un salto de línea por cada vez que escriba información en el archivo, así no se verán los textos en una sola línea.

Entonces el código quedaría de esta forma:

```java
import java.io.*; 

public void registro() 
{
    BufferedWriter bfw = null;
    String usuario, pass;
    System.out.println("Nombre de usuario deseado:");
    usuario = entrada.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Contraseña deseada:");
    pass = entrada.nextLine();
    try
    {
        bfw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("users.txt", true));
        bfw.write(usuario + "," + pass);
        bfw.newLine();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: "+ e.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if(bfw != null)
                //Para liberar recursos
                bfw.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: "+ e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

El algoritmo es básico, así que debes evitar que el **nombre de usuario** y **contraseña** no tenga una coma(`,`). Porque cuando hagamos la lectura de esos datos, vamos descomponer cada texto a través del método [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)).

Así que este método nos retorna un arreglo de objetos y se supone que en la primera posición debe estar el texto que corresponde al nombre de usuario y en el segundo, la contraseña.

Por último, para hacer el inicio de sesión es sencillo. Simplemente recorres cada línea de texto del archivo a través de un bucle e invocas al método `split` y posteriormente, usas el arreglo de objetos que retorne dicho método y así es como podrás comprobar si el nombre de usuario y la contraseña ingresada por el usuario existen en el archivo.

El código quedaría de esta forma:

```java
import java.io.*;

public void login()
{
    BufferedReader bfr = null;
    String usuario, pass, texto;
    System.out.println("Nombre de usuario deseado:");
    usuario = entrada.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Contraseña deseada:");
    pass = entrada.nextLine();
    try
    {
        bfr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("users.txt"));
        while((texto = bfr.readLine()) != null)
        {
            String[] t = texto.split(",");
            //Si el nombre de usuario y contraseña coinciden con lo que esté guardado en el archivo
            if(usuario.equals(t[0]) && pass.equals(t[1]))
                break; //Rompemos el ciclo, ya no es necesario seguir iterando
        }
        if(texto == null)
            System.out.println("Error: Nombre de usuario/password son incorrecto!");
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Has ingresado a tu cuenta!");
            //aquí puedes ejecutar algún SubMenú que pueda usar el usuario...
            /*
                more code..
            */
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: "+ e.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if(bfr != null)
                bfr.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: "+ e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Lo he implementado y me ha funcionado correctamente.